# checking property an object with a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object, smth like this

```
var obj = {
  page: 6,
  total: 12,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      email: "lawson@mail.com",
      last_name: "Larsen",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      email: "howell@mail.com",
      last_name: "Holl",
    },
  ],
  ad: {
    company: "Weekly",
  },
};
```

I want to ckeck this request object contains fields email. I try to do smth like this

```
var i = obj.data.length;
while (i--) {
  console.log(obj.data.hasOwnProperty("email"));
}
```

but it does not return me true

Comment: data is an array and not object. Instead do obj.data[0].hasOwnProperty("email");

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to check if email property is present in data array.

`obj.data.some((obj)=>hasOwnProperty('email'))`

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work, you have to iterate over array, or access some array index.

Your code would be:

```
console.log(obj.data[0].hasOwnProperty('email'));
```

Notice the zero index access.

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the each object in data using index..

```
while (i--) {
    console.log(obj.data[i].hasOwnProperty('email')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 'data' is an array, we can loop through the  dataset with **foreach** then find the 'email' property

```js
var obj = {
  page: 6,
  total: 12,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      email: "lawson@mail.com",
      last_name: "Larsen",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      email: "howell@mail.com",
      last_name: "Holl",
    },
  ],
  ad: {
    company: "Weekly",
  },
};

obj.data.forEach(data => {
  console.log(data.hasOwnProperty('email'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check all using loop For Each
obj.data.forEach( (item) => console.log( item.hasOwnProperty('email') ) );

// Check whether some objects in data have property 'email'
console.log( obj.data.some( (item) => item.hasOwnProperty('email') ) );

// Check whether every objects in data have property 'email'
console.log( obj.data.every( (item) => item.hasOwnProperty('email') ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special array method for this purpose. [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const response = {
  page: 6,
  total: 12,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      email: "lawson@mail.com",
      last_name: "Larsen",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      email: "howell@mail.com",
      last_name: "Holl",
    },
  ],
  ad: {
    company: "Weekly",
  },
};
const hasEmail = (item) => Boolean(item.email);

const everyItemHasEmail = response.data.every(hasEmail);

console.log(everyItemHasEmail)
```